# What is difference between the concept of Lock, Mutex and Spinlock?

Tags: concurrency, operating-system

I found some sentences：

- In computer science, a lock or mutex is a synchronization primitive: a mechanism that enforces limits on access to a resource when there are many threads of execution.
- A lock is specific to the AppDomain, while Mutex to the Operating System allowing you to perform inter-process locking and synchronization.

Therefore, is it true that Spinlock is a type of mutex?

However, I also found many compariosn between mutex and spinlock, stating that one is blocking and the other is busy waiting. But isn't mutex just an abstract concept, and spinlock its specific implementation?

I have researched some information, but I am still confused about the definitions of the terms mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, "lock" and "mutex" can be synonyms for the same thing. In general, a lock is a thing that prevents more than one thread or process or other entity from using the same resource at the same time.

"Lock" is somewhat of a broader term though. For example, we talk about "file locking," and "record locking," and "database locking," but you don't normally hear "database mutex," or "file mutex." Usually when we say, "mutex," we are talking about something that prevents two or more threads in the same process from using the same variables.

---

A [spin lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) is a lock. When we say "spin lock," we are talking about one particular way of *implementing* a lock. But we use it for the same reason we would use any lock--to prevent two or more threads/processes from using the same resource at the same time.

---

There's also, "[critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section)." That is, a section of code in which only one thread or process is allowed to execute at the same time. That name came out of the world of operating system kernels and in bare-metal embedded systems, where a critical section can be achieved for a single processor simply by disabling hardware interrupts. But, sometimes, you'll also see "critical section" used to describe a block of application code that's guarded by a lock.

---

Then, there's [*semaphores.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) The semaphore was invented way back in the 1960s. It was proposed as a primitive operation upon which, other synchronization objects could be built. One of the simplest ways to use a semaphore is to use it as a lock or mutex, and in older literature, you'll sometimes see the word "semaphore" used as a synonym for "lock."